# Get current IP connections (like netstat) with .NET

Tags: vb.net, tcp, udp

I'm trying to setup a Com-view sort of app, in Visual Basic,

I want my app to be able to pull IP address and process name that my computer is currently connected to.

So say if I was in a Skype call, I want to run the scanner, and pull the remote IP of the other user, along with what process it's using (Skype.exe) I've searched on Google, and found a few things on doing it through cmd but I had no luck, the closest I was to grabbing anything was 'This action requires elevated privileges' in the app.